# Why is this type annotation not showing up in FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi, python-typing

This is one of the endpoints in my FastAPI application:

```
@router.get("/", response_model=Page[DeviceConfigSchemaOUT])
async def get_device_configs(
    search: str | None = None,
    page: int = 1,
    size: int = 50,
) -> Any:
    ...
```

Which shows up like this in Swagger:

[image: endpoint without type annotation]

Why is there no type on the search parameter? I tried changing the declaration to an Annotation and manually specifying the type, but the result stays the same. This is using the latest FastAPI version 109.2 and Python 3.12.1.

Comment: I can't get what exactly is wrong. There are types for query params

Comment: @sudden_appearance Sorry for the confusion, the strange thing is that the page and size are typed correctly, but the search is not. I just found the answer on how to fix this and will post it. (Apparently it's a bug in FastAPI/ Pydantic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9900) in Pydantic 2 and FastAPI but there is a workaround as discussed in FastAPI discussions [(link)](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/10911#discussioncomment-8062800):

```
from pydantic.json_schema import SkipJsonSchema

@router.get("/", response_model=Page[DeviceConfigSchemaOUT])
async def get_device_configs(
    search: str | SkipJsonSchema[None] = None,
    page: int = 1,
    size: int = 50,
) -> Any:
    ...
```